# Plot a histogram with (X,Y) with X having some entries with multiple occurrences

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, mean

My goal is to plot a histogram or any other convenient graph actually with my data (X,Y) but the problem is that X is unsorted and most importantly has values with multiple occurrences. 
Thus, I am pretty sure I have to rearrange my data first to get a convenient graph; more precisely, I would like to get (newX, newY) where newX is composed of unique values and contains all the values from X and where newY is computed as a mean of the values of Y having the same antecedents x in X...

I hope the problem is clear and I thank you in advance for helping me solve this issue.

Comment: put some code, or at least what you have tried

Comment: It is in the nature of a histogram to accumulate multiple occurances into convenient bins. So maybe what you're after is *not* a histogram?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Plotting a [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html#examples-using-matplotlib-pyplot-scatter) of the x,y pairs could be a good start.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! 

Here is some code I wrote (I managed to sort the two arrays beforehand) @LiamYang

new_X, new_Y = zip(*sorted(zip(X, Y)))
plt.plot(new_X, new_Y)
plt.show()

Even though it is better than with an unsorted X, unfortunately the result shows a seesaw trend. Therefore, I thought about using a histogram (not with density in ordinate but with x and y values as input and an appropriate number of bins, if possible).

What do you mean @JohanC?